# SWIG Python wrapper for std::optional<>

Tags: c++, python-3.x, c++17, swig

I am writing a C++ 17 library, and a python 3 wrapper with SWIG (4.0.2). Some of the functions in the library return an `std::optional<>` type. I've looking for a wrapper for C++17's `std::optional<T>` for python through SWIG, but I can't find any online that can help me with my `T`, an actual type (this `T` is not the same `T` as in `template<typename T>`, it is the name of a class, in my case). This is what I've tried, and didn't work.

1. I've managed to retrieve the result inside an `std::optional<>` defining two functions:

```
%inline %{
bool is_optional_valid(const std::optional<T>& o) { return (o ? true : false); }
T get_data(const std::optional<T>& o) { return *o; }
%}
```

Inside python I use these functions like this:

```
opt = ... # call to C++ function that returns an std::optional<>
if is_optional_valid(opt):
    contents = get_graph(opt)
    del opt
    return contents

del opt
return None
```

But this returns the (probably expected) error:

```
swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'std::optional< T > *', no destructor found.
```

2. Using

```
%template(optional_T) std::optional<T>;
```

does not work since SWIG returns the error:

```
Error: Template 'optional' undefined.
```

3. I've been looking at typemaps at the official documentation but I can't make heads or tails out of it. And I'm not even sure that these apply in my case. For example, this github repository contains an `std_optional.i` for `float`

```
%typemap(in) std::optional<float> %{
    if($input == Py_None) {
        $1 = std::optional<float>();
    }
    else {
        $1 = std::optional<float>((float)PyFloat_AsDouble($input));
    }
%}
%typemap(out) std::optional<float> %{
    if($1) {
        $result = PyFloat_FromDouble(*$1);
    }
    else {
        $result = Py_None;
        Py_INCREF(Py_None);
    }
%}
```

but I'm not sure if I can use something like this to wrap a `T` (the name of a class). I tried, but I don't know what to put in the `????`.

```
%typemap(in) std::optional<T> %{
    if($input == Py_None) {
        $1 = std::optional<T>();
    }
    else {
        $1 = std::optional<T>(T($input));
    }
%}
%typemap(out) std::optional<lal::graphs::directed_graph> %{
    if($1) {
        $result = ????(*$1);
    }
    else {
        $result = Py_None;
        Py_INCREF(Py_None);
    }
%}
```

**Question** How can I wrap a `std::optional<>` with SWIG (for Python) for a `T` where `T` is the name of a class (if it is possible at all)? I could go about making a template class of my own with the methods given above. Something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class optional_wrapper {
    std::optional<T> m_optional_member;
public:
    // constructors...
    bool has_contents() const noexcept { return (m_optional_member ? true : false); }
    T get_contents() const noexcept { return *m_optional_member; }
};
```

and, lastly,

```
namespace my_library {
%template(optional_wrapper_T) optional_wrapper<T>;
}
```

but I don't think this is best practice for a C++ library since I'd be wrapping an existing type, with nothing new with respect to the wrapped type (please, tell me if you agree or not).

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first approach is the following. Assume you have a function called `call_to_function` with parameters `ARGS` (this could be `int, int`, or `std::string`) within a namespace `library`.

First, define and implement a template wrapper for `std::optional<T>`:

```
%{
template<class T>
struct LB__optional {
    std::optional<T> m_opt;
    bool has_contents() const noexcept { return (m_opt ? true : false); }
    T contents() const noexcept { return *m_opt; }
};
%}
```

Functions returning a `std::optional<>` should be called:

```
// note that this does not compile
template<class T>
LB__optional<T> call_to_function(ARGS...) {
    __optional<T> r;
    r.m_opt = library::call_to_function(ARGS...);
    return r;
}
```

Wrap the `LB__optional` and the `call_to_function`:

```
/* ---------- WRAP __optional ------------- */

template<class T>
struct LB__optional {
    std::optional<T> m_opt;
    bool has_contents() const noexcept { return (m_opt ? true : false); }
    T contents() const noexcept { return *m_opt; }
};

/* ---------- WRAP call_to_function ------------- */

template<class T> LB__optional<T> call_to_function(ARGS...);

/* ---------- INSTANTIATE LB__optional FOR SEVERAL TYPES ------------- */

%template(LB__optional_T) LB__optional<T>;

/* ---------- INSTANTIATE call_to_function FOR SEVERAL TYPES ------------- */

%template(call_to_function_T) call_to_function<T>;
```

Add some python code:

```
%pythoncode %{

def call_to_function(instantiated_type, ARGS...):
    r"""
    Document your function please

    Parameters:
    ----------
    * `instantiated_type` :
        A type for which `call_to_function` has been instantiated in the `.i` file
    * `ARGS` :
        Not actual parameter, but rather a shorthand for the parameters that should be passed to `call_to_function`.
    """
    
    if instantiated_type not in [TYPES FOR WHICH ]:
        return None
    
    opt = globals()[ "call_to_function_" + instantiated_type ](ARGS...)
    # we now have access to the "optional" because it is a type that
    # python knows about since SWIG wrapped it (a wrapper for __optional)
    if opt.has_contents(): return opt.contents()
    return None
%}
```